# How to clear unordered_map of unordered_map in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, unordered-map

I have a map as show below.

```
struct  B {
  int b1;
  int b2;
  int b3;
};

struct A {
  B a1;
  B a2;
};

unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, A>> outer_map;
```

I filled this inner_map with some elements, each inner map object also got initialised few elements.

So my question is how do you clear the outer_map ,so that i can fill the data freshly ?

Does outer_map.clear() works ? What exactly happens internally when you call clear here ? Can someone give little internal details ?

Comment: Do not do `typedef struct` in C++, it is redundant and does not give anything but harm.

Comment: `outer_map.clear()` should work, since the inner maps are held by value -- their destructors will be called. Other than that, your "example" has several issues (what's with the `typedef`s -- this isn't C?).

Comment: Thank you @DevSolar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run `outer_map.clear()` the keys (`int`) and values (`unordered_map<int, A>`) will all be removed. When they are removed, if there are any destructors to call, they will be called. This means that the destructor of any stored `unordered_map<int, A>`'s will be called, which in turn will remove all the `A`'s, calling their destructors as well.